# scan:started in the SQL Server profiler trace is generating incorrect indexid

Tags: sql, profiler, trace

I am running a trace with SQL Server Profiler (2008), to capture table/index scans, as I only need to know if we do have scans on large tables, I minimized the added columns to just EventClass (scan:started/stopped), dbname, objectid, starttime, spid and indexid.

In the captured result there are 2 problems, one is that some object ids are null (i.e. do not exist in the database in question / the db I filtered by), and the second problem is that some index ids are incorrect, e.g. some tables have just one clustered index, and the indexid provided by the trace being specified as 8, and another one is 122, although the table has fewer than 20 indexes.

I had suspected that the null object ids might be internal virtual tables, and I can live with that, but the incorrect index id, supposedly on standard user tables is throwing my performance troubleshooting out of balance.

Thanks in advance for any tips,

Naman

Answer (score 0):

If all you're trying to do is identify whether scans are taking place (as opposed to identifying the queries causing them) rather than using a trace, you may get better results looking at the system DMV [`sys.dm_db_index_operational_stats`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174281.aspx).
Table scans aren't broken out completely independently but appear in the `range_scan_count` column.

Also see `user_scans` in [`sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188755.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ed, isn't there a danger of missing some data due to entries being flushed out the metadata cache before we capture it? This is a quite heavily utilized environment, ~500 active users

Comment: @Naman - to be honest I'm not sure. This is aggregated data so I would have thought it was unlikely to be flushed automatically; as far as I know only a server restart or a manual flush will clear these figures down. If you feel this is a genuine concern you could set up a scheduled task taking a snapshot of the data at regular intervals.